# java spring named query and property file

Tags: java, spring

How to use named query. For example:

```
public interface A extends Base<SomeClass, Long> {
   @Query(value = "SELECT SUM(d.IS_OPEN) VW_VIEW d where d.value=?1", nativeQuery = true)
   SomeClass getValue(Long value);
}
```

How can I save SQL query into some properties file (not XML, not in Java class) and send name as parameter?

Comment: That is exactly where the `orm.xml` is for... Else you are basically on your own and need to implement your own mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Could proceed like this example:

this could be your generic select query on basis of primary key

```
query1=select {0} from {1} where {2} = {3}
```

Then can at the time of retrieving query you can use like this

```
 property = MessageFormat.format(query1,new String[]{"org_id","organization","PRIMARY-KEY","454545452"});
```

Similarly you can generalize the queries and set the values in your java code.
It depends on you what level of generalization you want.